# Conditional Coloring of Datatable in PF or var vs binding tags in a datatable

Tags: java, datatable, primefaces

I have a datatable and a collector. Each row in the datatable has a button and this button adds the corresponding row to the collector. I want to add conditional coloring to this datatable. Condition is whether the selected rows are in the collector or not.

```
<p:dataTable rowStyleClass="#{backingBean.selectedMemberList.contains(aMember) ? 'passive' : 'active'}" style="width: 100%;" id="dTable" var="aMember" value="#{backingBean.memberList}">
   <p:column>
   ...
  </p:column>

  <p:column>
      <p:commandButton id="btn_add" value="Add" update=":mf:op" process=":mf:op_uk">
          <p:collector value="#{aMember}" addTo="#{backingBean.selectedMemberList}" />
       </p:commandButton>
  </p:column>
```

backing bean:

```
List<Member> selectedMemberList;
List<Member> memberList;

//getter and setter methods
```

Above code does passive style class but does not add active style. I thought it is maybe because I can not pass var (which is request scoped) to backing bean.. So I tried binding the value to a backing bean value:

```
<p:dataTable binding="#{backingBean.anotherMember}" rowStyleClass="#{backingBean.selectedMemberList.contains(aMember) ? 'passive' : 'active'}" style="width: 100%;" id="dTable" var="aMember" value="#{backingBean.memberList}">
```

backingBean:

```
private Member anotherMember;
//getter and setter methods
```

but it did not work either. Does anyone have any recommendation about this issue?

PrimeFaces ver 2.2.1

EDIT:
css contains these fields:

```
.active{    
    background-image: none !important;   
}

.passive{
    background-color:gainsboro !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

EDIT & SOLUTION:

xhtml:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{backingBean.checkIfMemberInList(aMember)}" id="btn_add" value="Add" update=":mf:op :mf:op_uk" process=":mf:op_uk">
          <p:collector value="#{ukt}" addTo="#{backingBean.selectedMemberList}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

backing bean:

```
public boolean checkIfMemberInList(Member aMember){       
        for(int i=0; i<selectedMemberList.size();i++){            
            if(selectedMemberList.contains(aMember)){ 
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: does this rowStyleClass="#{(backingBean.selectedMemberList.contains(aMember))?'passive':'active'}" works for you (added extra brackets)?

Comment: does your class have !important on the background color , like this ?      background-color: #6CE26C !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    color: #000000 !important;

Comment: yes, I added the related css content..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can it be that `backingBean.selectedMemberList.contains(aMember)` return false all the time ?

If so ,

"play" with the `backingBean.selectedMemberList.contains(aMember)` , first try a method like backingBean.checkIfMemberInList(aMember) ,

```
boolean checkIfMemberInList(Member iMember){ 
    //iterate over the list and check if object exists , if so return true , otherwise false
}
```

Might be the objects are different ... `same id does not mean that their hash code is same`...

`you might consider override the int hashCode or boolean equals of the member class`

**Edit**

My suggestion for the checkIfMemberInList was just the first version to make it work, I really think that you should override the equals of your Member class , that way you will be able to use selectedMemberList.contains(memberObj)

[Implementing hashCode() and equals()](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html)

Comment: I "played" with the backing bean method and also added changed the update property of the command button, than it worked! Thanks for the answer. I added the final version, in case someone else needs it..

Comment: edited my answer... b.t.w your loop does not make sense... you iterate over selectedUyeKasaList while inside the loop you are not referring to it...

Comment: sorry, in order to make my post more readable I changed the name of the variables. I forgot to change that one, now I corrected.